# UK visitor visa question about EEA

Tags: visas, uk, europe, standard-visitor-visas

In my visitor visa application there is a question saying how many times have you visited the EEA.

I am not sure what to answer here as I entered to France and stayed there for a few days but went directly to Spain for a few days and then left doing stopover in Netherlands. So my question is, did I enter the EEA once or twice?

I think once but when I select that option only gives me the chance of putting one country instead of all the countries visited in the EEA at once. Thanks

Comment: Looks like a badly worded question. Note that when you answer more than one, it will ask only about the **last** country visited (which I suppose would be Spain in your case). I would probably answer "two to five" and then give the detail about your stay in Spain.

Comment: If you have an entry stamp from France, then France would be the best answer since it can be easily verified.

Comment: What exactly does the question say?

Answer (score 3):

All three countries are members of the European Economic Area, so you've made one visit to the EEA.

Enter that as your answer, along with France as the country you visited.

Elsewhere the form will ask for any additional information you may wish to provide in connection with your application. Add the additional countries there. There's no need for great detail. Listing the countries and approximate dates should suffice.